# Why is the image contains the source files when build through docker compose?

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I have this docker file -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HrManagement.dll"]
```

placed in

[image]

When building the image through the windows cmd, and running the image subsequently, i see that the app folder lists the below files -

[image]

However, when i build via docker-compose file in Visual Studio, I see the below ones-

[image]

Additionally, i see the src folder as well in the container -

[image]

Why is this difference seen when building the SAME docker file through the above methods?

The below is the docker-compose.yml file-

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  hrmanagement:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}hrmanager
    build:
      context: ./HrManagement
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=mypass
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1450:1433"
    volumes:
      - sql-server-vol:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  sql-server-vol:
    external: true
```

placed in

[image]

Comment: Is it using a Dockerfile placed in the top HrManagement directory? What happens if you change `dockerfile: ./Dockerfile` to `dockerfile: ./HrManagement/Dockerfile`?

Comment: @HansKilian: Added screenshot to show the location of compose file.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem, for me it works as it should. Could you upload your project setup to github (without your actual source code, the template project will be fine)